# Team Foundation Service Build Error

Tags: tfs, azure, publish, azure-devops

I am using TFS Preview to publish to Azure using the `AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml` process template for the build definition. I am getting following error and am unsure how to fix this:

> Summary Debug | Any CPU  1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
>   $/HelloWorld/Trunk/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.sln (':Publish'
>   target(s)) - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s), View Log File 
>   C:\a\src\Trunk\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.sln.metaproj: The
>   target ":Publish" does not exist in the project. 
>   $/HelloWorld/Trunk/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.sln compiled
>   $/HelloWorld/Trunk/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.sln (':Publish'
>   target(s)) - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s), View Log File  No Test Results 
>   No Code Coverage Results

Comment: Have you download the PublishProfile from your Windows Azure portal and configured to use with TFS Publish setting?

Comment: No I havent. Do you have information on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you are trying to deploy directly from your TFS to Windows Azure, you need to setup a direct connectivity from your TFS machine to Windows Azure using Windows Azure Subscription ID, certificate etc. When you download .publishsetting configuration from your Azure management portal and use with TFS, the connection can be made to Portal and then your Windows Azure Package will be deployed. This process is needed with TFS onpremise and TFS on Azure (which one is you using?).

This article [Automated Build and Deployment with Windows Azure SDK 1.6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/12/06/automated-build-and-deployment-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-6.aspx) describe how it can be done. Please try to start from here and see your problem is resolved.

Comment: Perhaps their is misunderstanding here. I am not trying to publish from VS 2012 to Azure but from TFSPreview as outlined in this article http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/#step3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to deploy your solution to a Azure Web Site or Azure Cloud Service?  From the error it appears you are trying to deploy to a Cloud Service but to not have a Cloud Project (ccproj) in your solution.

If you add a cloud project to your solution or simply create a new solution and select Cloud -> Cloud Service in the new project dialog in VS it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do: total time: 10 minutes

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/